# C# Image in rich text file not centered when loaded into rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I created a rich text file in OpenOffice Writer that includes an image with its alignment centered and tried to load the file into a rich text box in my C# WinForms app. Problem is the image is aligned left instead of centered. Here's my code:

```
private void DisplayStartPage()
{
    rtbMain.ReadOnly = false;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(OurProject.MainPage.StartPageContent, 0, OurProject.MainPage.StartPageContent.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(OurProject.MainPage.StartPageContent, 0, OurProject.MainPage.StartPageContent.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;
        rtbMain.LoadFile(ms, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }
    rtbMain.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Is this problem caused by the code above or could it be the app I used to create the rich text file?

Comment: is `OurProject.MainPage.StartPageContent` a String? It should be a byte buffer, so the problem is likely however you load the content, which you didn't show

Comment: Actually, OurProject.MainPage.StartPageContent is a byte array.

Comment: What is the version of the RichEdit Control of your RichTextBox wrapper? The `50W` version is better suited to work with general RTF Syntax. You need .Net Framework 4.7.2+ to have this version available by default. At run-time, inspect the `CreateParams` property, check whether you see `RICHEDIT50W` among the values. Then, test your syntax with MS Wordpad: these two have stricter syntax compatibility.

Comment: @Jimi: Wow, this sounds interesting! Do you have pointers to these changes??

Comment: @TaW There's also the `60W` version, the one that comes with Office (IIRC, 2007+). You can override CreateParams to set the class name and also use this, if available. About the RichEdit (RichEdit and MsftEdit): [About Rich Edit Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls). I don't know whether there's a comprehensive documentation on the changes and compatibility with (any standard of ?) *generic* RTF. If there's one guy that knows about it, that's Murray Sargent. See the [MSDN blog pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/).

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Framework 4.8, to give you an idea of what I'm working with.